# What is this strange code signing certificate for iPhone iPCUHost-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I noticed iPCUHost-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX showing up in my keychain and Xcode code signing list.  What's this and where is it coming from? Can I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

This is the certificate from the iPhone Configuration Utility. If you delete it, you won't be able to sign your code for use on an iPhone and other various authentication issues will occur. Otherwise, it's safe to delete.

If you accidentally deleted it and you want it back, follow the instructions [midway through this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2063630&tstart=120).

Comment: When you say can't sign, you mean you can't code sign distribution build or adhoc build when I delete this?